# Kendogrid tooltip on locked columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-tooltip

I'm having an issue with the kendogrid and locked columns. When I try to add the tooltip on a locked column it nevers shows. I have used the filer setting to do it,

$("#gridDataInput").kendoTooltip({
            filter: "td:nth-child(2)", 
            position: "right",
            content: function(e){
                debugger
                var dataItem = $("#gridDataInput").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(e.target.closest("tr"));
                var content = dataItem.Messages;
                return content;
            }
        }).data("kendoTooltip");

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99kvf.png)

When the column is not locked everything is just fine, as soon as I lock it, the tooltip is never displayed.

I've been stuck on that issue for a couple of day now, and even googleing is of no help. any suggestions anyone?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Kendo keeps locked columns in a distinct table in the grid. Your first call links the tooltip with the table containing the unlocked columns. You will need to define a second call linked to the locked column table. In my case I used this code:

```
$(".k-grid-header-locked").kendoTooltip({
            filter: "th",
            content: function (e) {
            var target = $(e.target)
            return target[0].dataset.title;}})
```

Good luck.

Answer (score -3):

You might want to try this :

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/layout/tooltip/overview

This shows a demo of tooltip to disabled columns though. Still give it a try.The idea is to wrap your column in a parent div and then show tooltip for the parent.

Comment: This should be a comment. It doesn't provide an answer to the person asking the question, only "try this" with links to documentation.